# Need Help on Embedded Tomcat ( logging + session replication)

Tags: tomcat

I am using Tomcat version 5.5 and have two questions.
I am starting tomcat through Embedded Tomcat.Like for example :

```
Embedded tomcatServer = new Embedded();

//engine

//host

//context

//connector

tomcatServer.start();
```

Question 1 :(related to logging)

Tomcat starts successfully and application is working fine but "Tomcat" logs(much concern of tomcat logs rather then application specific logs) are not getting generated in tomcat log directory.
For double check when i starts tomcat manually through startup.sh then tomcat logs are getting generated in log folder of tomat.
I have also searched that prior to version 5 there was one method setLogger/setDebug in org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded Class.But in version 5.5 its not available...plz help how to configure in order to enable logs thorugh Embedded Tomcat.

Question 2 :(related to session replication)

As thorugh Embedded Tomcat server.xml does not works(not used by tomcat) so need help in writting java code for `<Cluster>` element (as this is the main element for session replication).
I am able to replicate the session when i start tomcat manually or through startup.sh which uses server.xml but now i want to do the same session replication through Embedded Tomcat Class.Please Help..

Thanks in Advance.

Vikas

vikas31jain@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re #1: Set up `java.util.logging` properly ([see the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html)).

Re #2: Download the source code for Tomcat and search for `server.xml`. There is probably some class which reads it. There, you can also find the code which configures clustering.

Comment: @ Aaron : Re #1 : java.util.logging can be used for the application logs but i was asking about tomcat specific logs or more specific tomcat server logs. For Re #2 :If we are using Embedded class to start Tomcat then it does not user server.xml rather it uses the properties given in the argument of the code(in my case java code).Like for ex : connector = tomcatServer.createConnector(addr, port, false);

Comment: Re #1: Tomcat uses jul, too. Check the config files of a non-embedded tomcat to see how it has to be configured. Re #2: Read my answer again.

Comment: Thanks Aaron.I found the way(code) in order to configure cluserting.But i am still facing logging(tomcat specific) issue.I am lil bit new in tomcat.Could you please suggest some way.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the file `conf/logging.properties` how to configure Tomcat logging. And read the docs: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add AccessLogValve for logging - the it is specified in server.xml. You can also add it programmatically